# When uploading image it does not take me the correct file name Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, upload

I'm having trouble loading images into my project. The unusual thing is that I upload a cover image "imagen", and other documentation as "urls". Both codes are identical and are through the same controller, but the cover ("imagen"), although it is saved on the server correctly, is not taking the correct file name with the function $imageName

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
       if($request->hasFile('imagen')){
        $imagenes = $request->file('imagen');

        foreach ($imagenes as $imagen) {
            $imagenName=time().'_'.$imagen->getClientOriginalName();
            $request['imagen']=$imagenName;
            $file->move(("urls"),$imagenName);
        }
       }

        $siniestro = Siniestro::create($request->all());

        

        if($request->hasFile('urls')){
            $files=$request->file('urls');
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $urlName=time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
                $request['siniestro_id']=$siniestro->id;
                $request['url']=$urlName;
                $file->move(("urls"),$urlName);
                File::create($request->all());
            }
        } 

       
        return redirect()->route('siniestros.index')
        ->with('success','Siniestro cargado con éxtio');
    }
```

blade view:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="imagen" class="form-label">Cover</label>
   <input type="file" name="imagen" class="form-control">
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: url upload - work fine]

[image: "imagen" upload - see name file]

As seen in the controller, the codes are practically identical, but in the one I have an error in, it is not taking the name format that I am indicating. I clarify that both fields, in their respective tables, have the format VARCHAR (191)

Comment: Your question is not clear at all ! what you are trying to do ? specify the problem please

Comment: @AlaChebil not taking the correct file name, when i upload image

Comment: i suggest you a solution in a comment try it and tell me if it worl

Answer (score 0):

Hello try adding this function to your controller

```
public function getRandomName($length, $image): string
{
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    };
    $name = $randomString . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image->move(public_path('/images/products'), $name);
    return $name;
}
```

this function give a random name to your image and upload it to your public_path in laravel

**and then in your controller :**

```
if($request->hasFile('urls')){
        $files=$request->file('urls');
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $urlName=$this->getRandomName(8,$file); // change 8 with the desired file name length.
            $request['siniestro_id']=$siniestro->id;
            $request['url']=$urlName;
            File::create($request->all());
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is whit "Imagen" imput, not "url" buddy